# i/o Bus Standards & Device Controllers

Tags: io

I'm really confused about bus standards like ide,ata,sata,pci etc.

I have just read this article : 1https://superuser.com/questions/350582/when-a-disk-read-or-disk-write-occurs-where-does-the-data-go/350592#350592
So if we talk about hard disk drive; hdd logic board contains a microcontroller,buffer-ram,motor driver etc.This microcontroller communicates with the motor driver for reading and writing sectors to hdd platers.As i know a microcontroller is combination of cpu,registers,io ports,ram etc.Also there must be firmware inside the microcontroller.

My first question is how hdd microcontroller clock frequency is determined?

And according to above article why there is a word like "sata drive"? I mean if "ata" or "sata" etc. are just bus interfaces between the cpu and device controllers why "ata","sata" or "pci" words become a prefix for peripheral devices?

I really want to understand deeply about communication with peripheral devices.Above article i understood that two seperate communications occur when we want to read sectors from hdd,
first is between "cpu - device controller" and  second is "device controller - hdd".So how these seperate communications work each other?

Finally if "ata" or "sata" are interfaces that just stand for "cpu&memory(dma)-device controller" communication gateway, why this interface is slower than the front side bus(fsb)?i mean if i speak for dma transfer, after disk controller reads one sector from hdd it must transfer this sector to memory right?So why these slow bus interfaces are used for communication between the memory and device controllers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be more appropriate on [su] (well, it's at least not appropriate here as it doesn't appear to be a programming question). Why did you stray away from that site all the way to over here to ask the question?